# How to call zenity from cron script?

Tags: cron, zenity

Example script `error.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

zenity --error --text='Something very bad has happened!'
```

My `incron-config`:

```
~/Documents IN_MOVED_TO ~/scripts/error.sh
```

If I run `error.sh` in terminal GUI dialog pops, but not in above incron scenario.

How can I make zenity to pop that dialog when I move file in Documents folder?

Answer (score 23):

Found answer [here](http://promberger.info/linux/2009/01/02/running-x-apps-like-zenity-from-crontab-solving-cannot-open-display-problem/). Add to `~/.bashrc`:

```
xhost local:$USER > /dev/null
```

and then use zenity in script evoked by cron like this:

```
zenity --error --text='Something very bad has happened!' --display=:0.0
```

adding `--display=:0.0` is what's important

Comment: --display=:0.0 was important. But now I have same problem for service. It doesn't show anything if I put script as service!

Comment: What is the first part, xhost local:$USER > /dev/null, used for? It works fine with just --display=:0.0.

Answer (score 12):

To run a GUI command on cron, you'll have to tell cron what display the program should use. For that you use:export DISPLAY=:0

For a zenity notification each 30 minutes, edit with `crontab -e` and set a job like:

```
*/30 *  * * *  export DISPLAY=:0 && /somedirectory/your_zenity_script.sh
```

Detailed how to: [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=105250)

Answer (score 3):

There's another possible solution if you want it to work regardless of
username, by finding the active user of the X display, using
ConsoleKit (the command `ck-list-sessions`). Assuming the below script
is run as root, it will show a zenity message to the current active
user on your computer:

```
#!/bin/bash
ACTIVE=$(ck-list-sessions | awk -F' = ' '
    function f(){if(A=="TRUE"){P=U"\t"D;gsub("'"'"'","",P);print P}}
    $1=="\tunix-user"{U=$2} 
    $1=="\tx11-display"{D=$2} 
    $1=="\tactive"{A=$2} 
    END{f()} /^[^\t]/{f()}
')
USERID=${ACTIVE%    *} # tab
USERNAME=$(getent passwd $USERID|cut -f1 -d':')
DISPLAY=${ACTIVE#*  } # tab

DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" su $USERNAME -c "zenity --error --text='Something very bad has happened!'"
```

The little awk script is just for parsing ck-list-sessions and
outputting the username and display of the user that is active (could
also require that it's a local connection if you want to exclude ssh
-X users, if you want).

(I use this in a [backup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/User%3aUnhammer/backup) script that runs on plugging in a USB
drive.)