# cronjob not firing

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, python3

I must be doing something ridiculously wrong here, but I'm not seeing it.

I want to run:

```
python3 /home/web/Code/python/hourly-script.py
```

Which runs from the command fine, it displays a notification popup.

In `crontab -e` I put:

```
* * * * * python3 /home/web/Code/python/hourly-script.py
```

To test it running, I should get a popup every 1 minute.  I dont get any popups.

From the command line, when I run `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` I get:

```
Dec 17 07:44:01 web-XPS-15-9570 CRON[16643]: (web) CMD (python3 /home/web/Code/python/hourly-script.py)
Dec 17 07:45:02 web-XPS-15-9570 CRON[16879]: (web) CMD (python3 /home/web/Code/python/hourly-script.py)
Dec 17 07:46:01 web-XPS-15-9570 CRON[17114]: (web) CMD (python3 /home/web/Code/python/hourly-script.py)
Dec 17 07:47:01 web-XPS-15-9570 CRON[17489]: (web) CMD (python3 /home/web/Code/python/hourly-script.py)
Dec 17 07:48:01 web-XPS-15-9570 CRON[17988]: (web) CMD (python3 /home/web/Code/python/hourly-script.py)
Dec 17 07:49:01 web-XPS-15-9570 CRON[18287]: (web) CMD (python3 /home/web/Code/python/hourly-script.py)
Dec 17 07:50:01 web-XPS-15-9570 CRON[18544]: (web) CMD (python3 /home/web/Code/python/hourly-script.py)
```

Which would indicate that its running every minute, so why am I not seeing a popup?

I'm running on ubuntu.  The python file itself is executable:

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 web web 148 Dec 17 07:34 hourly-script.py`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call zenity from cron script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85612/how-to-call-zenity-from-cron-script)

Answer (score 1):

The cronjob is in fact firing, but as my limited research goes (running a Minecraft server with cron), cronjobs do not output to the default CLI, TTY or GUI. To get the output, you need to give the popup a location to pop up, which will be the GUI. This probably needs to be done in your script, although I do not know how.